# Notepad++: Disable/lock zoom

Tags: windows-8.1, notepad++, touchpad, microsoft-surface-pro

I have a Surface Pro 3 with the type cover, which includes a touchpad.  While the touchpad is a nice feature to have, it is difficult to use with Notepad++ for one reason: pinch zooming.  Because the entire trackpad serves as the mouse buttons, and because I tend to navigate the cursor with one finger and click with the other, I frequently inadvertently trigger the pinch-zooming gesture.  I don't want to have to reset the zoom every five minutes for as long as I have this tablet.  I furthermore have no conceivable need for zoom functions in Notepad++.  Is there a way to either stop zooming in Notepad++, disable pinch zooming, and/or configure Notepad++ to ignore multitouch gestures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this plugin: http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-zoomdisabler/

It can disable keyboard zoom and mouse zoom.

Comment: This works!  No more palm-resizing via touchpad while copy/cut/pasting.  Copy the .dll into C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins , then close Notepad++ and reopen.  WIN!